# How to capture the response of a query in GraphQL Relay

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I am new to relay, I have a query that delivers a response, which I can see in the network tab of the inspector, but what I dont understand is how to grab that response for use in my component. Could someone please explain that?

My query is

```
const query = graphql`
query AdvisorProfileQuery($id: ID!) {
    node(id: $id) {
        ...on Advisor {
            name
            postalCode
            products
            referralCode
            status
            updatedAt
        }
    }
}`;
```

and runs through the renderer

```
const QueryRenderer = LoadingQueryRenderer(AdvisorProfile, query);
export default ({ i18n }) => {
return (
    <>
        <QueryRenderer
            params={{ id: id }}
        />
    </>
);
};
```

but what is the variable name that holds that data that is returned to the component? I want to pass that data as a prop to another component.

This is how the response looks
[image: relay response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the example from [official docs](https://relay.dev/docs/en/query-renderer)

```
import React from 'react';
import { QueryRenderer, graphql } from 'react-relay';
 
const Example = (props) => {
  return (
    <QueryRenderer
      environment={environment}
      query={graphql`
        query ExampleQuery($pageID: ID!) {
          page(id: $pageID) {
            name
          }
        }
      `}
      variables={{
        pageID: '110798995619330',
      }}
      render={({ props }) => {
        if (props) {
          return <ChildComponent page={page.name} />;
        }
        return <div>Loading</div>;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

you can consume the data inside the QueryRenderer render like usual props